# Как преобразовать многомерный массив в объекты другого массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть многомерный массив. Нужно с помощью цикла преобразовать вложенные массивы в объекты с подходящими парами ключ-значение (автор,текст) и сохранить в новый массив.

```
let messages = [
   [ "zloy-zloy", "Мы с Алешей сегодня на иксбоксе рубились, потом в маке поели, потом ему новый телефон купили, и два часа с горок в Нескучном саду катались."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "У Алеши завтра день рождения."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "Он мой дед. Ему будет 81 год."],
   ["Вы", "LOL"]
 ];
```

В итоге должна получиться структура: Простой массив [{объект1}{...}{объектN}]

Сам цикл легко дался, но вот не приложу ума как сохранить полученные значения в массив в виде объектов.

```
let newMessages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
  newMessages.author = messages[i][0];
  newMessages.text = messages[i][1];
}
console.log(newMessages);
```

Comment: ВОЗМОЖНО ЭТО ПОМОЖЕТ https://xhtml.ru/2020/javascript/lets-flatten-that-multi-dimensional-array/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте переменную как объект в цикле, и уже этому объекту добавляйте свойства. а потом через `push` положите в результирующий массив.

```js
let messages = [
   [ "zloy-zloy", "Мы с Алешей сегодня на иксбоксе рубились, потом в маке поели, потом ему новый телефон купили, и два часа с горок в Нескучном саду катались."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "У Алеши завтра день рождения."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "Он мой дед. Ему будет 81 год."],
   ["Вы", "LOL"]
 ];

let newMessages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
  let item = {};
  item.author = messages[i][0];
  item.text = messages[i][1];
  newMessages.push(item);
}
console.log(newMessages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом reduce

```js
let m = [
   [ "zloy-zloy", "Мы с Алешей сегодня на иксбоксе рубились, потом в маке поели, потом ему новый телефон купили, и два часа с горок в Нескучном саду катались."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "У Алеши завтра день рождения."],
   ["zloy-zloy", "Он мой дед. Ему будет 81 год."],
   ["Вы", "LOL"]
 ];

let newMessages = m.reduce((prev,curr)=>{ prev.push({author:curr[0], text:curr[1]});return prev; },[]);

console.log(newMessages);
```